# Pandas Data Frame from nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

Given the following json dataset snapshot what is the best way to turn it into a pandas Data Frame?

Reading the file into a data frame ends up to [image: this] which is not exactly usable.

I am currently using `json_normalize` to turn `location` and `sensor` to separate Data Frames [image]

but trying the same approach with `sensordatavalues` gives me the following error[image]
Is this because `sensordatavalues` is an array object?

To make things worse, in some `sensordatavalue` records, the `id` key is missing

Just to make it a bit more challenging for you Pandas Gurus, Is there a way to do all the above in the same Data Frame?

```
        "location": {
            "indoor": 0,
            "exact_location": 0,
            "latitude": "37.36",
            "altitude": "17.0",
            "id": 13487,
            "country": "GL",
            "longitude": "26.962"
        },
        "sampling_rate": null,
        "id": 105462750,
        "sensordatavalues": [
            {
                "value_type": "temperature",
                "value": "18.70",
                "id": 226552256
            },
            {
                "value_type": "humidity",
                "value": "99.90",
                "id": 226552257
            }
        ],
        "sensor": {
            "id": 25666,
            "sensor_type": {
                "name": "DHT22",
                "id": 9,
                "manufacturer": "various"
            },
            "pin": "7"
        },
        "timestamp": "2020-01-19 19:10:38"
    },
```

Comment: thats because your sensordatavalue is list of dictionary, you need to explode the list and then apply the json_normalise function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pd.Series.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to unpack the list into individual rows.

```
exploded = df['sensordatavalues'].explode()
exploded
# 0    {'value_type': 'temperature', 'value': '18.70'...
# 0    {'value_type': 'humidity', 'value': '99.90', '...
# Name: sensordatavalues, dtype: object
```

The index is maintained, with duplicates, so this can be easily rejoined to the original data.

```
joined = df.drop(columns='sensordatavalues').join(exploded)
joined
#                                             location sampling_rate         id                                             sensor            timestamp                                   sensordatavalues
# 0  {'indoor': 0, 'exact_location': 0, 'latitude':...          None  105462750  {'id': 25666, 'sensor_type': {'name': 'DHT22',...  2020-01-19 19:10:38  {'value_type': 'temperature', 'value': '18.70'...
# 0  {'indoor': 0, 'exact_location': 0, 'latitude':...          None  105462750  {'id': 25666, 'sensor_type': {'name': 'DHT22',...  2020-01-19 19:10:38  {'value_type': 'humidity', 'value': '99.90', '...
```

Then you can use `json_normalize` as before.

```
json_normalize(joined['sensordatavalues'])
#     value_type  value         id
# 0  temperature  18.70  226552256
# 1     humidity  99.90  226552257
```